# How can I share a folder with Samba on a NTFS drive on startup?

Tags: samba, automount, shared-folders

On startup, I want a certain folder on an automounted NTFS drive (mounted on `/media/Data`), of which I've got ownership, to be shared with `Samba`. It should grant access to guests, but they shouldn't be able to edit or delete the files in there.

What is the best way to share a folder with this configuration on Samba on startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure why you've assumed terminal commands are the way to share folders with Samba. They are not.
What you need to do, assuming samba is already installed, is edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, a samba config file, and add the share to the bottom.

Example:

```
[some_name]
    path = /media/Data/folder_name
    writeable = no
    guest ok = yes
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I still had to change file permissions for the NTFS drive though. The question and answer for this can be found [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/85975/how-do-i-share-a-folder-on-a-ntfs-partition-over-the-network).