# How do I share a secondary internal drive?

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, samba

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have two HDDs. One for the OS and one for Storage (actually called Storage, even). I have three computers. This one running Ubuntu and two others running Win 7. 
What I'd like is for the Storage drive to be completely accessible and editable by the Windows machines. 
I've gone through sharing. I've gone through attempting sharing permissions. I'm not used to Linux and have been banging my head on the desk for hours now reading similar posts. I've yet to be able to read anything on any of the shares I've made. 
MY problem is that the Windows machines don't have access to the drive I'm trying to share.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I share a folder on a NTFS partition over the network?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/85975/how-do-i-share-a-folder-on-a-ntfs-partition-over-the-network).

Comment: Your `Storage` drive need to be one of the Windows Understandable format(NTFS,FAT,etc).  Try formatting it in that format.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Samba. Please look at:
[what is samba](https://www.samba.org/samba/what_is_samba.html)

and [how to use it](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch01.html)

Comment: Ah man you beat me to it.  [Ubuntu has a guide too](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20%28Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal%29%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link only answers are not acceptable here, please edit this to actually include the information on how to fix the issue..